# Animated UIImage in UITextView with TextKit

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit, nslayoutmanager

I have a `UIImage` that contains multiple image frames and a duration which was sliced together from an animated GIF file. If I load the image in a `UIWebView` it will animate as expected, but I want to use a `UITextView` instead. The obvious choice is to use TextKit with a custom `NSLayoutManger` and many custom `NSAttributedString` attributes to achieve various drawing effects. I have a single `UITextView` that I'd like to give a `NSAttributedString` that contains `NSTextAttachment`s for all of the images I need to display inline. It's working fine except for when I load one of these animated `UIImages`, they do not animate through their frames. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I've come up with a theoretical option:

1. For each animated image add a custom defined attribute
2. When layout manager goes to draw backgrounds, iterate this attribute to locate the positions of the attachment.
3. Callback to the text view to create `UIImageView`s with the animated image, add as a subview, and call `startAnimating`

I have yet to try this, but it's fairly hacky. I'm wondering if there's a better option.

In summary: I want to animate a `UIImage` inside a `UITextView` via `NSTextAttachment` inside a `NSAttributedString` without the necessity for extra `UIImageView` objects. You can ignore the fact that this was previously done with a `UIWebView`. `UIImage` has properties (`images`, `duration`) for setting up animated frames, which I currently have configured. If I assign it to a `UIImageView` it animates, if I set it as a `NSTextAttachment`, no animation.

I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Wondering the exact same thing this morning.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot, of how it looks in the WebView, that you are trying to replicate with UIImage and UITextView. This will help visualize it better and help with the answers.

Comment: @pteofil I can't screenshot because you won't know that the image is animating, it would just look like a static image. To clarify: I want to animate a UIImage inside a UITextView via NSTextAttachment inside a NSAttributedString *without* the necessity for extra UIImageView objects. You can ignore the fact that this was previously done with a UIWebView. UIImage has properties (images, duration) for setting up animated frames, which I currently have configured. If I assign it to a UIImageView it animates, if I set it as a NSTextAttachment, no animation.

Comment: I understand much better now. But the comment you made to clarify would be much better integrated in the question where everyone can see it easily.

Comment: If you hold references to the `NSTextAttachment` object and manually change the `image` property after a delay, do you see anything change? If so you could subclass `NSTextAttachment` and recreate the animation behaviour.

Comment: @Robert Yeah that's an option I considered, subclass `NSTextAttachment` with a `CADisplayLink` that would analyze the animated `UIImage` and determine when it needed to update the image property of the text attachment. It seems only slightly less hacky than adding `UIImageView` subviews to the text view. I will give it a try though and see the feasibility.

Comment: @afrederick how did you solve this issue? I'm looking exactly for the same. Add a `GIF` as `NSTextAttachment` to the `UITextView` and it only stays static, like a regular image.

Comment: @IvanCantarino Yeah it's currently not possible. I asked an apple engineer at WWDC and they confirmed that CATiledLayer which is what backs UITextView will not animate. The solution is to use the text attachment as a "placeholder" with a frame but no image, then add a subview on top of the text view with your animated image at the same frame.

Answer (score 4):

I think this behaviour is because the `UITextView` doesn't display the attachments using `UIImageView` subviews. When I observe the view hierarchy with and without the `NSTextAttachment`s added to the `UITextView`, I don't see any new views (you can observe the view hierarchy using View Debugging in Xcode, or by saying `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`). Presumably, the `UITextView` just draws it's attachments directly.

That said, one way I can think of to include an animatable attachment is to create an animated `UIImageView` yourself as a subview of the `UITextView`, place it exactly where the `NSLayoutManager` places the `NSTextAttachment`, and scroll it whenever the UITextView scrolls. You can get the rectangle of the `NSTextAttachment` from the `NSLayoutManager` by calling `boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:` (possibly in `layoutManager:didCompleteLayoutForTextContainer:atEnd:`).

Comment: Yes this is the "theoretical option" I spoke about in my question. It's fairly hacky and I'd like to avoid this approach if possible since it will be fragile and require a ton of extra management of those `UIImageView` subviews. The `UITextView` I'm using is contained within a `UICollectionViewCell` so the cell would have to manage their positions and lifecycle. When initially researching I did what you said: I inspected the subviews of the text view in the hopes it nested some image views that I could animate, but there are no subviews, all rendering is done within a `CATiledLayer`.

Comment: If the textview is within a collection view, you'll have to manage the image views' positions and lifecycles in the same way as you do for the text view. You can create the UIImageView subview/s whenever you create the UITextView, and place them in didCompleteLayout. If the textview is within a collection view, I presume you're not using the scrolling features of the textview - if that's the case, you wouldn't need to bother to scroll the image view.